# Align part of content of <TD> belowe each other

Tags: html, css

I wounder if you with CSS can line a everything that has the same class below each other even if they are in another table row? I want all the VS to be aligned below each other and then the teams on left and right side of them.

```
<tr>
    <td>Some info</td>
    <td>Some info</td>
    <td id="teams"> A team <span class="vs">VS</span> Another Team</td>
    <td>Some Info</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Some info</td>
    <td>Sine info</td>
    <td id="teams"> A team name <span class="vs">VS</span> Another Team name</td>
    <td>Some Info</td>
</tr>
```

Now its like this:

[image]

And i want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: If you're already using a table, why won't you use 2-3 different columns for this purpose?

Comment: Split your text over 3 `<td>`'s?

Comment: Can i have 3 different <td> under the same header? Mostly that's why i don't want to split in <td>'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By splitting this `td` into 3 different `td`'s and using `colspan="3"` on the coresponding `th`.

Take a look at that <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/nmMaN/1/)</kbd>

it's just a basic layout, alter it to your needs..

**HTML:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>info 1</th>
        <th>info 2</th>
        <th  colspan="3"> A team VS Another Team</th>
        <th>info 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some info</td>
        <td>Some info</td>
        <td class="teams left">A team</td>
        <td class="vs">VS</td>
        <td class="teams right">Another Team</td>
        <td>Some Info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some info</td>
        <td>Some info</td>
        <td class="teams left">A team name</td>
        <td class="vs">VS</td>
        <td class="teams right">Another Team name</td>
        <td>Some Info</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table
{
    width: 100%;
}
td
{
    text-align: center;
}
th:nth-child(3)
{
    column-span: 3;
}
.teams
{
    color: red;
}
.vs
{
    color: green;
}
.left
{
    text-align: right;
}
.right
{
    text-align: left;
}
{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split the TD you have now into three seperate TDs.